# Why is equals not mandatory to implement in java.util.Comparator?

Tags: java, interface, comparator

Either in Javadoc as well as the code itself, Comparator interface defines:

```
 int compare(T o1, T o2);
 boolean equals(Object obj);
```

But then this gives no probs compilating:

```
 Comparator a = new Comparator() {      
     @Override public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        //..
     }
 };
```

But this does:

```
 Comparator a = new Comparator() {      
     @Override public boolean equals(Object comparator) {
        //..
     }
 };
```

How its done for the interface for allowing us not to override method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all [JavaDocs explain](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) clearly that you should implements this method:

> Additionally, this method can return true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator. Thus, `comp1.equals(comp2)`implies that `sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))` for every object reference `o1` and `o2`.

But later:

> Note that it is always safe not to override `Object.equals(Object)`.

How is it possible not to override `equals()`, even though it is part of an interface? Because this method is already implemented for each and every object in Java ([in `Object` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))).

The declaration in the interface is there only to emphasise the importance of `equals()` with regards to `Comparator` by adding extra JavaDoc explanation.

BTW if your comparator is stateless you should have only one instance of it - in which case the default `equal()` implementation is just fine.

Comment: I had read the second part, but I mean, is an interace extending also object like a normal newable instance then? Or do you mean an interface is aware of what methods could be already implemented in any object so it does not force them?

Comment: @user1352530 actually, neither. Interface is not aware of `Object`. But when you are implementing an interface, you always inherit, directly or indirectly, from `Object`. This means you already inherited `equals()` and others, so the compiler is not complaining. On the other hand note that when you have an instance of any interface, you can still call any `Object` method on it, not barely methods of that particular interface.

Answer (score 0):

Beczuse every object already implements equals().

In reality specifying equals() again in the Comparator interface definition accomplishes precisely nothing except giving a chance to document the contract and its relationship with compareTo().