# Why don't implement all method in interface Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

Today, I'm trying to learn some features in Java 8, specific about Lambda Expressions. I create a new Comaparator like this :

```
Comparator<String> strCom = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

When I read code inside Comparator interface, I have got confused. Althrough interface Comparator have two method *compare()* and *equals()*, we don't need implement all of them. I had found some reason why we don't need implement method *equals()* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11758069/2865414). But i also read in javadocs

> *If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile*. **[What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)**

**So, can someone help me understand this ? Do not override *equals()* is still legal ?**

Comment: you could override `equals` if you´d like to know if two comperator are equal

Comment: `Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object). However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct comparators impose the same order.`

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582823/why-is-it-not-necessary-to-override-both-methods-of-interface-comparator-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is trying to introduce the concept of interfaces through a simple example, but it ends up being misleading.

Take this code for example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void foo();
    public void bar();
}

public class Super {
    public void foo() { System.out.println("foo"); }
}

public class Sub extends Super implements MyInterface {
    public void bar() { System.out.println("bar"); }
}
```

This is perfectly valid code, despite the fact that `Sub` only explicitly implements one of `MyInterface`s methods. It's easy to see why this is valid: `foo()` is already implemented by `Super`, and that implementation is inherited by `Sub`.

The exact rule goes like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5):

> Unless the class being declared is abstract, all the abstract member
>   methods of each direct superinterface must be implemented (§8.4.8.1)
>   either by a declaration in this class or by an existing method
>   declaration inherited from the direct superclass or a direct
>   superinterface, because a class that is not abstract is not permitted
>   to have abstract methods (§8.1.1.1).

While the rule only talks about direct superclasses, it is technically also true for indirect superclasses, as method inheritance bubbles down through the hierarchy.

Given that `equals()` is implemented by `Object` and `Object` is the direct or indirect superclass of every class, you don't have to provide an implementation for `equals()`.

Answer (score 4):

equal is not needed to implement because it is inherited from the Object class, as everything in Java is an Object

As you can see in the documentation the equal Method is already defined in the Object class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

You only need to implement the equals method if you want to check if two Comparators have the same data and therefore are "equal", but this is probably not what are you looking for, as Comparators normally do not hold any instance variables

Comment: The Javadoc says that two comparators are "equal" if they impose the same ordering of objects. So the behaviour of equals() depends only on the behaviour of your compare() method - no instance variables involved.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou If you've got two comparator instances of the same class, their behaviour will only be different if their instance variables are different too. (Unless you're doing something really bad, like base the behaviour on which thread they're running in, or an external global variable.)

Comment: @biziclop No, you don't need any instance variables at all (and Comparators typically don't have instance variables, although some do). Two Comparators may be of different classes, both implementing the Comparator interface. They will be considered equal if their respective compare() methods always return the same value for any given parameters. In other words, two equal comparators are interchangeable, even though they are different classes.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou A lot of my comparators **do** have instance variables. In practice it happens more often than you'd think, while it's vanishingly rare for two comparators of different classes to produce the same order. The point though is that if they **are of the same class and they still behave differently**, more often than not that's because of their instance variables.